# Linq Select and Aggregate within a single iteration

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

Is there a way to do this with linq without enumerating the `fooCollection` twice?

```
var fooCollection = // get foo
var selectedIds = new List<int>();
var aggregateContent = String.Empty;

foreach (var f in foo)
{
    selectedIds.Add(foo.Id);
    aggregateContent += foo.Content
}

var results = new FooResults
{
    Content = aggregateContent,
    SelectedIds = selectedIds
};

return results;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549218.aspx) method:

```
var result = fooCollection.Aggregate(new FooResult(),
                                    (r,f) => 
                                    { 
                                        r.SelectedIds.Add(f.Id);
                                        r.Content += f.Content;
                                        return r;
                                    });
```

This has the benefit of being side-effect free. I dislike side effects in my LINQ. =)

Comment: I think you nailed it there Jens. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is one possiblity, but I consider it a hack:

```
var aggregateContent = String.Empty;
var selectedIds = foo.Select(x => { aggregateContent += x.Content;
                                    return x.Id; })
                     .ToList();
```

I would go with the loop you already have. It is much cleaner as any LINQ solution you could come up with.

Comment: I see what you mean - using Linq to both select and and increment something is not exactly CQRS. However I am going to work with the aggregate function Linq provides as this expresses what I'm trying to do clearly and feels less hacky. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
foo.ForEach(x => { selectedIds.Add(x.Id); aggregateContent += x.Content; });
```

I would recommend not concatenating the Content into a string, but to use a `StringBuilder` instead.

**EDIT**

If you don't have a LINQ extension library that implements `ForEach` for `IEnumerable`, here is a method you can use:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action) 
{ 
    foreach(T item in enumeration) 
    { 
        action(item); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please note: `ForEach` doesn't exist for `IEnumerable<T>`. It is a member method of `List<T>`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel; I extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: I second @Daniel 's comment: List.Foreach has nothing to do with linq. (The question asks for a LINQ solution).

Comment: That's what he asked for literally, but did he not *really* ask for an efficient implementation?

Comment: I can also `.ToArray()` the fooCollection in order to use `ForEach`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is to have a Linq statement produce two results. 
The whole idea of linq is to allow a concise functional programming style without side effects.

If you want multiple results and good performance, you should not be using Linq, and use a regular foreach.

Comment: I agree that I am not keeping inline with CQRS, but by using the Aggregate function I am expressing a function which is *only* causing side effects - the results of which are clear.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it too so I write my own like this

```
public static IEnumerable<V> SelectAggregate<T,V>(this IEnumerable<T> items,V seed,Func<V,T,V> func)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        seed    = func(seed,item);
        yield return seed;
    }
}


var array = new int[]{ 1,2,3 };
var sumArray = array.SelectAggregate(0,(seed,item) => seed + item).ToArray();
//// { 1,3,6 }
```